# Drivers not loading due to changing ownership of /usr/lib to root:root

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I have changed the ownership of /usr/lib by mistake as root:root by running the below command:

```
sudo chown -R root:root /usr/lib/
```

Now, the wireless drivers are not loading and also I am not able to shutdown or restart the system without using the terminal. I changed back some of the folders' ownership to the username and temporarily solved few problems. Do I need to format my system? If anyone has a better solution , please help!